# Python - Type Object 'str' Has No Attribute 'string'

Tags: python

I've searched around and found similar questions, but cannot seem to figure out how to apply it to my issue. I'm creating a shape with a predefined size, but first I need to figure out how to add/multiply the "-" character by a certain number and print it within classes. Here's my code:

```
def __str__(self):

    string = "-" * 4
    return string

def main():

    print(str.string)
    return
main()
```

end goal is to create a box like this:
[image]

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me tell you one thing! creating function in the name of keywords is not preferred as the compiler may not behave expected! So calling str.Variable_name creates problem

Just make your code like this :

```
def get_box():
    return '-'*3

print(get_box())
```

This should work! Let me know if not -

**Update**

```
Class Box(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.box = "-"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.box*3

#create an object
box = Box()
print(box)
```

Check and let me know whether this works...

Comment: `print(get_box())` You forgot the `()`.

Comment: I would do that, however I have to use the class __str__ for the string portion of this project, as we are learning about classes in my programming class. He wrote out a bunch of pre-made classes and we have to fill in the missing portions.

Comment: You didnt mention that it is inside a class! Fine, now i have updated my answer accordingly, do check and let me Know if it helps! @JohnGordon thanks for finding it out! i edited!

Comment: Glad that it helped :)